# Plotly: How to add markers at specific points in plotly line graph (python / pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have a df (below) and want to write a function that will return a `plotly` line graph with data labels at specified points within the dataset (this graph tracks the success of a promotion, so I want to mark when the promo begins and ends - but that is not the same as the start and end of the dataset itself).

```
index   date    x_sales y_sales
0   2019-10-24  0   27
1   2019-10-25  0   30
2   2019-10-26  0   34
3   2019-10-27  0   36
4   2019-10-28  0   29
```

The `plotly` docs are unclear about how to add annotations and the only relevant StackOverflow question I can find is about R.

Ideally, I would like a graph like the one here:

[image: sales graph with x_sales and y_sales]

but with a little label for `start date` and one for `end date` on one of the lines.

My current code is as basic as it gets:

```
fig = px.line(df_g, x="date", y=df_g.columns)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `customAnnotations()` in the code snippet below will produce this figure using `add_annotation()` for each specific point you'd like to annotate:

[image]

As you've specified, this produces a figure where the start and end of your specified period are annotated. Let me know how this works out for you and we can adjust it to your specific needs.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# data sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {3: '2020-08-03',
                4: '2020-08-04',
                5: '2020-08-05',
                6: '2020-08-06',
                7: '2020-08-07'},
                'title_sales': {3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 6, 7: 2},
                'regression_sales': {3: 4, 4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 4},
                'causal_sales': {3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 3}})

df.set_index('date', inplace = True)

   
def customAnnotations(df, xStart, xEnd, yVal):
    # xStart = '2020-08-04'
    # xEnd = '2020-08-06'
    # xVal='date'
    # yVal='regression_sales'
    
    
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[yVal].values, marker_color='black'))
    per_start = df[df.index==xStart]
    per_end = df[df.index==xEnd]

    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='rgba(0,0,200,0.8)',size=12),
                                        x=per_start.index[0],
                                        #x = xStart
                                        y=per_start[yVal].iloc[0],
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text='Period start = ' + per_start.index[0] + '  ',
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        xref="x",
                                        yref="y"))

    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='rgba(0,0,200,0.8)',size=12),
                                        x=per_end.index[0],
                                        #x = xStart
                                        y=per_end[yVal].iloc[0],
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text='Period end = ' + per_end.index[0] + '  ',
                                        #ax = -10,
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        xref="x",
                                        yref="y"))

    fig.show()
    
customAnnotations(df=df, xStart = '2020-08-04', xEnd = '2020-08-06', yVal='regression_sales')
```